# Update item set json data - Lambda Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

so my table is like the following

```
MyTable
  CustomerID <- key
  Customer <- key
  temp <- map
    23 <- map (this is hour of the day value)
      count <- field
      totalTemp <- field
```

Now i know this isn't correct, but it is an example of what I am trying to do

```
UpdateExpression:"SET temp.hour Add temp.hour.#count :c,
   temp.hour.#totaltemp :tt",
```

So i want to update the hour that i get from a js function that I have that outputs the current hour(0-23), then add count (c just equals 1) and temp this just keeps a running total of the inserted values.

I have been struggling with this for 2 days now and just cannot find the code examples to do this